# WCF Odata services with Entity Framework exception guarding

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, odata

How does one enable the ability to see the full exception using an OData wcf service like you would using a local Objectcontext/dbcontext?  In development we can't figure out how to have the service supply the full error message in response.

Right now, if you don't supply a required field for an entity you get a generic "request could not be processed error" 500 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried these: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/06/18/debugging-ado-net-data-services.aspx